# How to urge a user to update the user's browser when entering a web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, cross-browser, updates

I'm wondering if there is some way to "force" a user to update the user's web browser.

For instance, if a user enters my site and he or she is using an old version of a browser, an area of the page that is ordinarily hidden will be revealed. And that revealed area will contain a browser update recommendation and a hyperlink to an external page where the user can download a new version of the user's browser or update the current version.

Specifically, here are the two aspects of my goal for which I need guidance:

1. How to recognize the browser and it's version, and
2. How to show a hidden area specific to the browser the user is currently using. (Maybe there will be an area for each type of common browser, so the question would be how to show the associated area.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my research I came across this site which offers a small JavaScript-based notification component:

http://browser-update.org/index.html

This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can for example do this in ActionFilterAttribute. For example it can look like following:

```
public class WarnAboutOldBrowserAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

        //check if it browser warning was already checked
        if (request.Cookies["checked"] != null)
        {
             return;
        }
        //exmaple is for IE 6
        if (request.Browser.Browser.Trim().ToUpperInvariant().EqualsExact("IE") && request.Browser.MajorVersion <= 6)
        {
          filterContext.Controller.ViewData["RequestedUrl"] = request.Url.ToString();

          filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "OldBrowserWarning" };
        }
        //add cookie for caching
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie("checked", "true"));
        }

    }
}
```

Of course you have to add also a view called "OldBrowserWarning" to display information to user.

Other way is to add warning in _Layout.cshtml and in above code set proper flag in ViewBag